# How to handle large http JSON response body

Tags: java, spring, httpclient

There are REST-API that return large JSON data
example result:

```
{
   "arrayA":[
      {
         "data1":"data",
         "data2":"data"
      },..
   ],
   "arrayB":[
      {
         "data1":"data"
      },..
   ]
}
```

"arrayA" possible record just 0 to 100 records but "arrayB" can be possible 1 million to 10 million record
it make my java application out of memory.
My question is how to handle this case.

Comment: looks like your response is a collection of collections. You might wanna implement pagination. Request small portions at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different concerns here and IMO the question is too broad because the best solution may depend on the actual use case.

You say, you have a REST API and you would like to “protect” the server from Out Of Memory Error, I get that.

However, assuming you’ll find the way to fix the OOM error on server, what kind of client will want to view tens of millions objects at once? If its a browser, is it really required? How long will take the JSON processing on the client side? Won’t the client side of application become too slow and the clients will start to complain? I’m sure you’ve got the point.

So the first way is to “re-think” why do you need such a big response. In this case, probably the best solution is refactoring and changing the logic of the client-server communication

Now, another possible case is that you have an “integration” - some kind of server to server communication.

In this case there is no point in adding the whole json response at once or even doing streaming. If you’re running in the cloud for example, you might want to add this huge json string to some file and upload to S3, for example and then provide a link to it (because S3 can deal with files like this). Of course there are other alternatives in non AWS environment.

As a “stripped-down” idea you might get the Request, create the temp file on the file system, write the data to it in chunks and then return the “FileResource” to the client. Working chunk-by-chunk will ensure that the memory consumption is low on your java application’s side. Basically it would be equal to downloading the file that gets generated dynamically. When you close the stream you might want to remove the file.

This would work best if you have some kind of “get heap dump” or any data dump in general functionality.

Comment: You right I forgotten somethings important